# Run time errors in code converted from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have this piece of code in VB

```
 Private Function ReadProfileViewPlotOptions(ByVal SavePath As String) As ProfileViewOptionsType
            Dim FileName As String
            Dim filenumber As Short
            Dim InInt As Integer
            FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(SavePath, "cfgpropt.sys")
            If Not System.IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
                With ReadProfileViewPlotOptions
.ViewConcave = CBool(GetSetting(My.Application.Info.Title, "ProfileViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", CStr(1)))
-----
```

I converted it into **C#** Like this

```
private static Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.PlanViewOptionsType ReadPlanViewPlotOptions(string SavePath)
        {
            var title = ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0]).Title;
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.PlanViewOptionsType functionReturnValue = default(Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.PlanViewOptionsType);
            string FileName = null;
            short filenumber = 0;
            int InInt = 0;
            FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(SavePath, "cfgplopt.sys");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                functionReturnValue.ViewConcave = Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", Convert.ToString(1)));
-----
}
```

During run-time , my code is breaking at the line

> functionReturnValue.ViewConcave =
>   Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions",
>   "ViewConcave", Convert.ToString(1)));

The error shown by the compiler is **"Format Exception Unhandled" .String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."**

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What is the value coming back from GetSetting?

Comment: Try to switch the inner "Convert.ToString" into a "Convert.ToBoolean"

Comment: @Kevin MSDN says this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.getsetting(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the setting is not found `GetSetting` returns a default value of `"1"`, ie a `string` containing the value `1`. This cannot be converted to a `bool` via `Convert`. But as the last parameter of `GetSetting` must be a `string`, you could either use

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", Convert.ToString(true)));
```

or just

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", "true"));
```

Comment: I have a statement which is Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "ProfileViewPlotOptions", "ViewEdge", Convert.ToString(0)) ; shall i use Convert.ToString(false) for this ?

Comment: Yes, 0 is a representation for false, But you can just use "false".

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a string expects the input to be:

> A string that contains the value of either Boolean.TrueString or Boolean.FalseString.

Where TrueString is "True" and FalseString is "False".

If `GetSettings` returns a string that's neither of these then the method will raise a FormatException.

You will need to assign the return value of `GetSettings` to a variable and then either make sure that it's the correct format or do the true/false test yourself. However you are passing in `Convert.ToString(1)` as the default value so if the setting doesn't exist you'll be returning the string "1" which is neither "True" nor "False".

Change the default value to "True":

```
functionReturnValue.ViewConcave = Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", "True"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line

```
functionReturnValue.ViewConcave = 
    Convert.ToBoolean(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", Convert.ToString(1)));
```

with the following:

```
functionReturnValue.ViewConcave = 
    Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "PlanViewPlotOptions", "ViewConcave", "1")));
```

as the `Convert.ToBoolean` overload that accepts an integer will *correctly* convert `1` to `false` whereas the overload the accepts *a string* will fail to convert `"1"`  as this must be `"True"`/`"False"`

So providing your GetSetting will return a string that can be converted into an Int32 this will work

Comment: I am afraid when I say that  Its not the correct way. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: What if `GetSetting` returns `"True"` or `"False"`? Which I assume it does...